# Can I create a jXLS template spanning across multiple sheets

Tags: jxls

Is it possible to create a template that has multiple sheets and each sheets containing different set of formatting and completely different data. The sample shows where similar data is copied across multiple sheets but I am looking where each sheets contain completely different formatting and data is also different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple sheets in your template.
Remember to define *jx:area* at each of your sheet to mark what part of the sheet you want to process. Then use *JxlsHelper* to process all of them at once

```
JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(templateInputStream, outputStream, context);
```

This call will read all the defined xls areas using *XlsCommentAreaBuilder* and then process each area at its starting cell.